# How to create an Angular 2 component that exposes methods

Tags: angular

I'm just getting started and I'm wondering how I can communicate between 2 component.

I read that I can use a service, but that's mainly for sharing data, but I don't want to pass data between components.

Let's say that I'm developing a modal component which is not showed by default.
I use this component 3 times on my page, for 3 different types of messages, and my application shows 3 buttons, in a total other component.

Now, when I click the first button, I want to open modal 2, button 2 should open modal 2 and popup 3 should open modal 3.

Here's an example component:

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
// Defines the 'innovana-message-box' component.
@Component({
    selector: 'innovana-message-box',
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="isShowed">This is my message box.</div>
    `
})
export class InnovanaMessageBoxComponent {
    public isShowed = false;

    constructor() {
        //this.Show();
    }

    Show() {
        this.isShowed = true;
    }
}
```

How can something like this be achieved?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [one-way data binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax). I suggest you to read the whole [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) article and it's desirable to read most of the official docs articles. As for me, they are quite simple .